# Will I need a visa to leave the US in order to live in Sweden permanently?

Tags: usa, visa, sweden

I'm currently a Jamaican immigrant living in the US. I'm not a green card holder nor am I a citizen but I do currently have DACA. I have family living in Sweden and would like to live there permanently. Would I need to obtain a visa from my home country and have it shipped to the US in order to travel to Sweden? Will I have any complications such as deportation at the airport?

Comment: From a practical perspective, no airline is going to let you board for a trip to Sweden without a visa. So you'll have to sort something out. In order to travel, you would have to pay a fee and apply for an I-131. But I *think* that only matters if you wish to return to the U.S.with the same protections. If not, you're probably fine to leave whenever you like. There would be no point in deportation if you're leaving the country anyway

Comment: What family do you have in Sweden? are they citizens? The EU has good rights for its citizens and their right to a family

Comment: Yeah they are citizens, born and raised in Sweden. Would that be an advantage?

Comment: @SamJones, Sam: Whether it is an advantage depends on the nature of the relationship and on Swedish law.  EU freedom-of-movement law doesn't generally apply to the family of EU citizens in the country of citizenship.

Answer (score 2):

You need to work with the embassy of the target country you want to move to, in the country you currently reside.
So in your case, that would be the Swedish Embassy in the US.

Traveling back to Jamaica would not help you.